# Can I fly this six motor drone?

Tags: aircraft-design, pilots, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, airplane, quadcopter

My body weight; 70kg,
Drone weight; 50kg,
Props length 0.7m,
6 motors (2hp each),
Total weight 120kg,
Total horsepower 12,
Each motor runs 3000rpm,
Please can I fly it.
Thanks!!!

[drawing of the drone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv8Uo.jpg)

Comment: Are you asking our permission or whether it'll fly?

Comment: What have you tried so far to get these numbers?

Comment: @Jamiec  he is asking whether. If he was asking permission it would have been "May I fly this six motor drone" ;-)

Comment: Welcome to AviationStackExchange. You may notice that this site is specifically set up for very detailed and defined questions to get factual and verifiable answers. If you want to get an answer and not risk your question being closed due to it being too general, make your question as detailed as possible. Include any work and research you have done so far as well as what issue you are having in finding the answer yourself. Including what area or jurisdiction the question pertains to will also help.

Comment: Also, if you are asking whether you can fly any drone as the onboard pilot in command, the answer is no in the US. By classification, a manned drone is no longer a drone. Although, it may be considered an ultralight aerial vehicle if you keep its empty weight under 254 pounds, its top speed under 55 knots, and its fuel capacity under 5 gallons. In hat case, yes. Just as long as you stick to the rules of Title 14 of the Code of Federal Regulations Part 103.

Comment: @Jamiec may he is asking us how does he can work that

Comment: If your question is specifically about a small unmanned aerial vehicle with no humans onboard being flown by a remote pilot, please visit the Drone and Model Airplane Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is a classic case of "**if you have to ask, the answer is a firm NO!**"  People actually in a position to design larger than featherweight aircraft, regardless if they will carry humans or not, are people who *know what they are doing*, which is to say they do not post newbie questions critically short of detail.  There's far more to flying than opposing the force of gravity with a lift mechanism.

Comment: And don't forget to send it to us

Comment: Crucially: does prop length refer to the length of a single blade or the prop disc diameter?

Comment: Does rapidly rising off the ground and then quickly tumbling out of control until it violently impacts terra-firma, endangering any people nearby, count as "flying"? Because that seems like an entirely likely outcome here. "Well, it flew... right up until the loss of control, the crash, the explosion, and the fire. But for 1.2 seconds, it was, in fact, flying."

Comment: 12hp isn't enough to lift a person like this, it's low for a paramotor and they have a huge wing. If you look at any of the man-carrying multirotors, they have much more power. Colin Furze's hoverbike had about 50bhp and barely flew, DCL's Big Drone is 217bhp - https://dcl.aero/explore/big-drone/

Comment: @Alberto L. Bonfiglio he did say "please," though, which sounds like asking permission.

Answer (score 9):

No, you may not fly this drone. It weighs much more than 55 lbs. At least in the United States, you have to have an FAA clearance and hold an FAA Part 107 Certificate to operate anything that heavy.

Comment: Excellent answer to a question in *dire* need of a reality check! Welcome to Av.SE, and please come back often!